# How to delete a node in a tree?

Tags: c++, algorithm, pointers, data-structures, tree

I am  trying to implement a simple binary tree in c++ using pointers.

I have successfully implemented insertion and traversing, but I am having some problem when I try to delete a node:

my main function is:

```
main(){
node* root=createNode(1);
root->left=createNode(2);
root->right=createNode(3);
root->left->left=createNode(4);
root->left->right=createNode(5);
root->right->left=createNode(6);
root->right->right=createNode(7);
inorder(root);
//till here it works fine

delete root->left->left;     //problem starts here
cout<<"\n";
inorder(root);               //exception is thrown here...
return 0;
```

}
`

inorder function is very basic recursive function:

```
void inorder(node* root){
if(root!=NULL){
    inorder(root->left);
    cout<<root->data<<" ";
    inorder(root->right);
}
}
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the delete line?

Comment: What exception is thrown? Are you sure it's an exception?

Comment: Does `createNode` set the `left` and `right` pointers to `null`?

Comment: @JosephMansfield, I bet it is sigsegv that crashes the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the `delete`, trying to access the deleted pointer will cause this problem. You probably want to add

```
root->left->left = 0
```

after the delete line.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set the `root->left->left` pointer to `NULL` i.e. It's point to nothing

In you code

```
main()
{
   node* root=createNode(1);
   root->left=createNode(2);
   root->right=createNode(3);
   root->left->left=createNode(4);
   root->left->right=createNode(5);
   root->right->left=createNode(6);
   root->right->right=createNode(7);
   inorder(root);
   //Now, Complete program will work

   delete root->left->left =  0;     //problem solved
   cout<<"\n";
   inorder(root);               // Do you still face any problem ?
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After the deletion of node, you need to reset the parent's left pointer to zero.
Not doing so can result in unpredictable results, depending on how memory management is implemented. Some systems take exception to references to freed up memory

Answer (score 0):

```
Your trying to delete node which has not null nodes in both right and left side, so you to delete node like this ..

/* deletes a node from the binary search tree */
void delete ( struct btreenode **root, int num )
{
    int found ;
    struct btreenode *parent, *x, *xsucc ;

    /* if tree is empty */
if ( *root == NULL )
    {
        printf ( "\nTree is empty" ) ;
        return ;
    }

    parent = x = NULL ;

    /* call to search function to find the node to be deleted */

    search ( root, num, &parent, &x, &found ) ;

    /* if the node to deleted is not found */
if ( found == FALSE )
    {
        printf ( "\nData to be deleted, not found" ) ;
        return ;
    }

    /* if the node to be deleted has two children */
if ( x -> leftchild != NULL && x -> rightchild != NULL )
    {
        parent = x ;
        xsucc = x -> rightchild ;

        while ( xsucc -> leftchild != NULL )
        {
            parent = xsucc ;
            xsucc = xsucc -> leftchild ;
        }

        x -> data = xsucc -> data ;
        x = xsucc ;
    }

    /* if the node to be deleted has no child */
if ( x -> leftchild == NULL && x -> rightchild == NULL )
    {
        if ( parent -> rightchild == x )
            parent -> rightchild = NULL ;
        else
            parent -> leftchild = NULL ;

        free ( x ) ;
        return ;
    }

    /* if the node to be deleted has only rightchild */
if ( x -> leftchild == NULL && x -> rightchild != NULL )
    {
        if ( parent -> leftchild == x )
            parent -> leftchild = x -> rightchild ;
        else
            parent -> rightchild = x -> rightchild ;

        free ( x ) ;
        return ;
    }

    /* if the node to be deleted has only left child */
if ( x -> leftchild != NULL && x -> rightchild == NULL )
    {
        if ( parent -> leftchild == x )
            parent -> leftchild = x -> leftchild ;
        else
            parent -> rightchild = x -> leftchild ;

        free ( x ) ;
        return ;
    }
}
```